# Wait for an animation to finish in unity3d

Tags: c#, animation, camera, boolean, unity-game-engine

I have an animation which plays in the `Update`-function, in a `Switch` case.

After the animation finishes, a Boolean is being set to true.

My code:

```
case "play":    
    animation.Play("play");     
    gobool = true;
    startbool = false;
    break;
```

The problem is my `gobool` and `startbool` get set immediately without finishing the animation. How can I let my program wait untill the animation is finished?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you need to do two things for this solution to work:

1. Start the animation.
2. Wait for the animation to finish before you play next animation.

An example of how this could be done is:

```
animation.PlayQueued("Something");
yield WaitForAnimation(animation);
```

And the definition for `WaitForAnimation` would be:

C#:

```
private IEnumerator WaitForAnimation (Animation animation)
{
    do
    {
        yield return null;
    } while (animation.isPlaying);
}
```

JS:

```
function WaitForAnimation (Animation animation)
{
    yield; while ( animation.isPlaying ) yield;
}
```

The do-while loop came from experiments that showed that the `animation.isPlaying` returns `false` in the same frame PlayQueued is called.

With a little tinkering you can create a extension method for animation that simplifies this such as:

```
public static class AnimationExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerator WhilePlaying( this Animation animation )
    {
        do
        {
            yield return null;
        } while ( animation.isPlaying );
    }

    public static IEnumerator WhilePlaying( this Animation animation,
    string animationName )
    {
        animation.PlayQueued(animationName);
        yield return animation.WhilePlaying();
    }
}
```

Finally you can easily use this in code:

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    yield return animation.WhilePlaying("Something");
}
```

[Source, alternatives and discussion.](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/37411/how-can-i-wait-for-an-animation-to-complete.html)