# Check if animation clip has finished

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

This is the simple code inside of update. sadly it is not working for me. Even I have set Wrap Mode to clamp Forever.

```
 if (trainGO.GetComponent<Animation>()["Start"].time >= trainGO.GetComponent<Animation>()["Start"].length)
 {
      blackTrain.SetActive(true);
      redTrain.SetActive(false);
 }
```

How can I check that animation clip have finished so that I can do some work? I don't want to use WaitForSeconds method, because I am working on Time and each time a new animation will be played,

Comment: I believe this is your answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110201/wait-for-an-animation-to-finish-in-unity3d

Comment: i think you didn't read the question completely! i have already check it

Comment: @snowYetis I don't want to use WaitForSeconds method.

Comment: I do not see  other options aside. Here is the documentation on animation events http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html

Comment: Have you tried `animation.isPlaying`? http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.IsPlaying.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically like this ...

```
PlayAnimation(); // Whatever you are calling or using for animation
StartCoroutine(WaitForAnimation(animation));

private IEnumerator WaitForAnimation ( Animation animation )
    {
    while(animation.isPlaying)
        yield return null;

    // at this point, the animation has completed
    // so at this point, do whatever you wish...
    Debug.Log("Animation completed");
    }
```

You can trivially google **thousands of QA about this** example,  http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/37440/view.html

If you do not fully understand coroutines in Unity, step back and review any of the some 8,000 full beginner tutorials and QA regarding "coroutines in Unity" on the web.

This is really the way to check an animation is finished in Unity - it's a standard technique and there's really no alternative.

You mention you want to do something in `Update()` ... you could possibly do something like this:

```
private Animation trainGoAnime=ation;

public void Update()
    {

    if ( trainGoAnimation.isPlaying() )
        {
        Debug.Log("~ the animation is still playing");
        return;
        }
    else
        {
        Debug.Log("~ not playing, proceed normally...");
        }
    }
```

I strongly encourage you to just do it with a coroutine; you'll end up "in knots" if you try to "always use Update".  Hope it helps.

---

FYI you also mention *"actually the scenario is: at specified time (Time/clock separately running). I have to play an animation thats why i am using update to check the time and run animation accordingly"*

This is very easy to do, say you want to run the animation 3.721 seconds from now...

```
private float whenToRunAnimation = 3.721;
```

it's this easy!

```
    // run horse anime, with pre- and post- code
    Invoke( "StartHorseAnimation", whenToRunAnimation )

private void StartHorseAnimation()
  {
  Debug.Log("starting horse animation coroutine...");
  StartCoroutine(_horseAnimationStuff());
  }

private IENumerator _horseAnimationStuff()
  {
  horseA.Play();
  Debug.Log("HORSE ANIME BEGINS");
  while(horseA.isPlaying)yield return null;
  Debug.Log("HORSE ANIME ENDS");
  ... do other code here when horse anime ends ...
  ... do other code here when horse anime ends ...
  ... do other code here when horse anime ends ...
  }
```

Comment: i know about co-routine and i don't want to use it

Comment: I am playing animation in update. checking a time then play animation accordingly

Comment: Hi Mohammad - can you explain why you prefer not to use a coroutine?  I am always telling people "don't use a coroutine if you don't have to", however in this case it's the only solution.  Pls explain what you are trying to avoid. Cheers!

Comment: there are two reason first, I am checking in update that animation have finished or not and co-routine will not properly work in update

Comment: and second reason is that i want to perform some action after the completion of animation and isPlaying will return always false if the animation is not playing which consequently execute my code again and again.

Comment: Hi @Mohammad - you really ***JUST CAN'T DO THAT***. You could do it inside `Update()` but it would be very messy - and totally unnecessary. You could change the state of a flag, along the lines `animationIsPlaying` if you like.

Comment: Hi @Mohammad - regarding doing something when the animation is finished, it clearly shows how to do that in the coroutine - that's just why you use a coroutine!

Comment: actually the scenario is: at specified time (Time/clock separately running). I have to play an animation thats why i am using update to check the time and run animation accordingly. And the the thing not over here additionally i have to run some code after completing that animation

Comment: thank you very much for your help. anyhow i have to use some more bool which will be frustrating as i have many animation

Comment: there are easier ways. when you post a new question make a note here so that people here can see the new question, good luck!

Comment: Ah!  what you ask is very easy, please look at the edit to the answer