# JavaScript -- Unity Check if animation has ended

Tags: javascript, animation, unity-game-engine

As the title says,

How do I check if the animation has ended ?

Comment: explain in brief.. one line question can not be answer.. show some code that you have write or some other work, expected output, current scenario.

Comment: I have only the code that starts the animation: animation.Play("camera_right");

Comment: try `animation.isPlaying`. If it is false, means it has ended. Also you can add an event tn last frame of animation that will call method that will tell you it has finished.

Comment: This question already has a huge, canonical answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35040426/294884

Comment: NOTE @NikolaZagorac.  Do NOT use "unityscript".  It is deprecated and being removed from Unity. The good news is, it is actually far easier to use c#.  Change to c# from today.

Comment: Well I only know JS but in the next school year I start learning C and other C languages so that's when I'll start using it, and i doubt Unity will remove it any time soon, not like Unity 6 will be cut next week. And there will be probably a plugin someone will make that lets you use js

Comment: Joe Blow is right. There is no reason to use js in Unity3D, no reason at all.

Comment: Except it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: It seems like you're using the legacy Animation component. I'd recommend using the Animator component. With this one it can be done like this:

The Animator component has a method "GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(layerIndex: int)" returning an object of type AnimatorStateInfo.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.html

The "AnimatorStateInfo" object has a property called normalizedTime which will give a float between 0 and 1 where 1 means the current loop of the animation has been played (finished) and 0 means it has just started.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorStateInfo-normalizedTime.html

As I don't know what exactly you're trying to achieve. I'd suggest to have a look at the IsName method of the "AnimatorStateInfo" class, with which you can check whether a certain state is currently playing.

greetings

Comment: Hi Wipster. This is not how you do it.  You do this .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35040426/294884

Comment: Hi @JoeBlow , the legacy Animation system is used in your post and apparently Nikola Zagorac is using that, so you're right. I'd not recommend to prefer that over the "new" Animator system though. With the Animation component it seems very redundant, you'd need a coroutine for every animation. I edited my answer.

Comment: Besides, when you use invoke, why not invoke a method after animation length, that sets a a flag, that the animation has finished? No need for a coroutine doing nothing for most of the time.

Comment: Hi Wipster, well said, good answer, but you DO need a coroutine to wait on the end of an animation (or indeed, to wait on anything)