# Animation state changes but not actual animation

Tags: 2d, sprite, unity-game-engine, animator

Been googling this but no luck.

Upgraded to Unity 5, trying to get extremely simple 2d sprite animation working. Have 2 clips, walk and idle, which have transitions triggered by a bool. (Same issue with an integer.) This all works. Changing the bool causes the animator to show its now playing the walk animation, however in the actual scene its still showing the idle animation. I can flip the bool but now in scene is playing the walk animation during both states (though the animator shows its switching to the idle animation when its supposed to.)

Have tried turning it on and off again, building the animator from scratch, swapping in different clips, setting the transition legth to 0, no change. Also did all the static batch/root animation options people suggested for other issues with u5.

Comment: BTW there are many helpful QA on ere about animation. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35040426/294884

Answer (score 1):

The issue was - two animators stacked on top of each other, one in a  child object. Sorry for the useless question.

Comment: no problem at all - but to help keep the boar tidy, could you just CLICK to "delete" this answer: then you can click to delete the question.  it's quite time consuming for the moderators to do it; if you do it yourself it's quicker.  See you on the next question!