# How can i check if playing animation is finished using Animator to be able to switch between two cameras?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have Main Camera. And another Camera called it AnimationCamera.
In a script i did i can switch between the two cameras by clicking on the C key.
But i also added a method that play a specific animation clip. I call this method from another script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera animationCamera;
    public Camera mainCamera;
    Animator _anim;

    private void Start()
    {
        animationCamera.enabled = false;
        mainCamera.enabled = true;
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            animationCamera.enabled = !animationCamera.enabled;
            mainCamera.enabled = !mainCamera.enabled;

            if (animationCamera.enabled)
            {
                _anim.CrossFade("Animation_Sign", 0);
            }
            else
            {
                _anim.CrossFade("Animation_Idle", 0);
            }
        }
    }

    public void PlaySignAnimation()
    {        
        animationCamera.enabled = true;
        _anim.CrossFade("Animation_Sign", 0);
    }
}
```

And the script i'm calling the method PlaySignAnimation:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sign_Wooden_Blank : Interactable
{ 
    public override void Interact()
    {
        var ac = GameObject.Find("AnimationCamera").GetComponent<AnimationCamera>();
        ac.PlaySignAnimation();
    }
}
```

Then in the Animator window i have two states: "Animation_Sign" and "Animation_Idle" the state "Animation_Idle" is for stopping the animation/s.

Then i also made that the default state will be the Idle and i also did a transition between the two states.
I also set the animation clip not to be in loop.

[image: Animator window]

The problem is in the script how can i check or how do i know when it finished playing the clip so i can switch back the cameras ?

```
public void PlaySignAnimation()
        {        
            animationCamera.enabled = true;
            _anim.CrossFade("Animation_Sign", 0);
        }
```

Here i switch it to the animationCamera enabled it to true.
But once the animation clip finished playing and it stopped i want to switch back in the script to the mainCamera making it enabled true and the animationCamera enabled false.

The problem is i don't have any flag/sign that tell me when the animation finished playing.

Comment: Check this post out, might be considered a duplicate however: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35040426/7750124.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this approach for manage an Animation Controller

[image]

as you can see the transaction between IdleClosed and ClosedToOpened happens when the variabile integer "stateMachine" it's equals to 1.

Into my update() method or similar, I have a the following code:

```
    var value = localAnimator.GetInteger ("stateMachine");

    if(value==1)
      EventDispatchManager.Instance.TriggerEvent (EventsDictionary.OPENING , sender);
    if(value==2)
      EventDispatchManager.Instance.TriggerEvent (EventsDictionary.OPENED , sender);
```

The class EventDispatchManager is a simple custom signal manager for my application, and can send and receive messages from any kind of object.

At the ending of ClosedToOpened animation I've setted an animation event that will change the "stateMachine" to 2  migrating to "IdleOpened" animation.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html <- you can find the documentation about animation events here.

Using this feature and returning into my code the following condition it will be true:

```
 if(value==2)

      EventDispatchManager.Instance.TriggerEvent (EventsDictionary.OPENED , this.gameObject);
```

So in another place I will have a listener, something like this....

```
Scripts.Managers.EventDispatchManager.Instance.StartListening (EventsDictionary.OPENED, listener: delegate {

        //DO SOMETHING WHEN THIS EVENT IS RAISED
    });
```

In this way I manage and kind of situation.

Comment: I found another way a bit more code but very simple i guess.

Answer (score 0):

My solution.

First i'm getting the length of each Animation clip in the Animator.
So i have a List of floats for each clip.

Then i changed the method at the bottom to be type of IEnumerator.
And using WaitForSeconds in this case the length is 10.
And in the script i'm calling this method just changed it to use StartCoroutine.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera animationCamera;
    public Camera mainCamera;
    Animator _anim;
    List<float> animations = new List<float>();

    private void Start()
    {
        animationCamera.enabled = false;
        mainCamera.enabled = true;
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

        foreach (AnimationClip ac in _anim.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips)
        {
            animations.Add(ac.length);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            animationCamera.enabled = !animationCamera.enabled;
            mainCamera.enabled = !mainCamera.enabled;

            if (animationCamera.enabled)
            {
                _anim.CrossFade("Animation_Sign", 0);
            }
            else
            {
                _anim.CrossFade("Animation_Idle", 0);
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator PlaySignAnimation()
    {        
        animationCamera.enabled = true;
        _anim.CrossFade("Animation_Sign", 0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(animations[0]);
        animationCamera.enabled = false;
        mainCamera.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

The second script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sign_Wooden_Blank : Interactable
{
    public override void Interact()
    {
        var ac = GameObject.Find("AnimationCamera").GetComponent<AnimationCamera>();
        ac.StartCoroutine(ac.PlaySignAnimation());
    }
}
```

Not sure if what i did is a good solution but it's working.