# How to run subsequent animations only after the previous animation is completed in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get it so that when a collider is pressed one animation is run and only when it's completed will another press of the collider activate the next animation.

I've been trying to follow this: [Wait for an animation to finish in unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110201/wait-for-an-animation-to-finish-in-unity3d)

But currently I'm running into an error saying "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'animation' of 'reduced_grill.WaitForAnimation(Animation)' ".

I'm still very new to this.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class reduced_grill : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject grill_standard;
    public Animator minimal_grill;
    public GameObject reduced_grill_obj;
    public GameObject grill_price;





    private IEnumerator WaitForAnimation(Animation animation)
    {
        do
        {
            yield return null;
        } while (animation.isPlaying);
    }




    IEnumerator OnMouseOver()
    {

           minimal_grill.GetComponent<Animation>();
           yield return WaitForAnimation();

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && minimal_grill.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("none"))
        {
            grill_standard.SetActive(true);

            reduced_grill_obj.SetActive(true);
            minimal_grill.enabled = true;
            minimal_grill.Play("minimal_grill_red", -1, 0f);



            CallLater.DoAfter(5, x =>
            {
                grill_price.SetActive(true);
            });


        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && minimal_grill.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("minimal_grill_red"))

        {


            minimal_grill.enabled = true;
            minimal_grill.Play("minimal_grill_exit", -1, 0f);
            grill_price.SetActive(false);
            CallLater.DoAfter(8, x =>
            {
                reduced_grill_obj.SetActive(false);

            });

        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && minimal_grill.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("minimal_grill_exit"))
        {
            grill_standard.SetActive(true);

            reduced_grill_obj.SetActive(true);
            minimal_grill.enabled = true;
            minimal_grill.Play("minimal_grill_red", -1, 0f);

            CallLater.DoAfter(5, x =>
            {
                grill_price.SetActive(true);
            });

        }

    }


}
```

*Edit*

I'm trying to add an animation event as per the suggestion below but for some reason I can't select any animation to input into the field box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use an AnimationController and use the visual editor to create animation routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add animation events at the end of each animation triggering each other. Have a look at:

[Unity Animation Events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html)

Comment: I added an event but I can't choose an animation into the "animation" field for the function waitforanimation.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to achieve? You have 2 or 3 animation states and you want to cycle through them following each other when mouse is clicked wait for the animation end before changing to next one? If so you can achieve this only using `Animator.SetBool`  method in the script and adjusting the animation exit and transition parameters in Animator.